# how to set space between two hyperlinks in css?

Tags: html, css

I have two hyperlinks in my page

```
<a>link 1</a><a>link 2</a>
```

I need to have space between these hyperlinks.
I wrote css like below for that

```
<style>
a {display:inline-block; margin-right:10px;}
</style>
```

but the problem is that `cursor:pointer` is also shown in the hover of "margin-right:10px;"

This does not feel like the space in between in the hyperlink.

How can I make space in between these without `cursor:pointer`?

Comment: If you only want a few spaces you could use `&nbsp;` in the actual HTML, or in CSS use `word-spacing:`

Comment: Give space between the `a` tags. `display: inline-block` sets space automatically if you do so.

Comment: Can't replicate. http://jsfiddle.net/erRC2/

Comment: What is the question? Are wanting the cursor to see the white-space as one of the links?

Comment: If you use padding - cursor will show. If you use margin - it won't.

Comment: i need wite-space between the links

Comment: As an update to James' Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/erRC2/1/ you can see the `padding` on the inside of the element, and the `margin` on the outside of the element. This `margin`  is the white space.

Comment: yes its working for me now before i use a:before .. th's y its happend

Comment: @user475464 if you used `a:before` in your actual implementation, why did you put just `a` in your question? It's impossible to help people when guesswork is involved.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap them in a `div` and style the div with `word-spacing: 10px;` :)

The more `word-spacing` the more space the less `word-spacing` the less space :)

Answer (score 0):

Just enclose all the hyperlinks in a div . After that turn to yuor style file and add  word spacing attribute e.g 10 pc

Comment: Could you provide an example and fix the typos plase?